# Choquet's theorem with the measure continuous at the given point

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a locally convex topological vector space and $K$ a nonempty convex compact subset. Let the set of extreme points of $K$ be $K_e$.

Then Choquet's theorem says that for any $u \in K$, there is a probability measure $m_u$ on the closure $\bar{K_e}$ such that $l(u)=\int_\bar{K_e}l(e)dm_u(e)$ for any continuous linear functional $l$ on $X$.

If $v$ is in $\bar{K_e}-K_e$, I can simply set $m_v$ as a point-mass at $v$. However, is there another measure $m'_u$ such that $m'_u(\{v\})=0$? Could anyone show me how to comstruct such a $m'_u$?

Comment: I think you meant "If $v$ is in $K - \overline{K_e}$, I can...". By Krein-Milman you have $\overline{K_e} - K \subset \overline{\operatorname{conv}K_e} - K = K - K = \emptyset$.

Comment: Oops I will edit it.

Comment: Choquet's theorem gives a probability measure on the set of extreme points.

Comment: Yes but that is only when $K$ is metrizable.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: In $\mathbb R^3$ take $K$ as the convex hull of $$\{(x,0,0): x\in [-1,1]\} \cup \{(0,y,z): y^2+z^2=1\}.$$ (Draw a picture!) Then $(0,0,0)$ is in the closure of the extreme points but not an extreme point itself. A representing probability measure is the Laplace distribution on $\{(-1,0,0),(1,0,0)\}$.